# How do I understand this Recursion Base Code Problem

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm learning the recursion concept in js, I got a very basic question of the base code returning problem.

```
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);  
}
```

So this is a simple factorial example of explaining the recursion.

**factorial(5) = 120**

My question is, why it's not returning 1 when the n reaches 1? After the return inside the if statement, the second return will continue to run? And if it return 1, the second return continue to run and it will do 5 * 1 forever (let's say n reaches 5)???

Comment: The recursion function will call itself in return, meaning `n` will be decreased one by one from each call.
Once n reaches 1, we need to finish the loop (repetitive call of the function ).
So it returns 1 because factorial(1) is 1.

Comment: When the deepest function in the recursive chain executes, `factorial` will return `1`. After that the execution continues from the point the previous recursive call was made until the caller is the original invoke which called `factory`. Returning from `if` block doesn't break the entire chain.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small example, adding some log's. The attribute `indent` was added to help on logs indentation, and for better understand what's happen.

On recursive calls (like on non recursive calls), when outer function calls the inner function, the current variables are stored somewhere on memory (on one stack), and then call the function.

When the inner function returns, the values will be restored.

If you see the log's of my example, the parameter `n` decrease the value on each call, but was restored after the inner function returns.

Answering to your questions:

`My question is, why it's not returning 1 when the n reaches 1?`

- when the `n` reaches `1`, the function returns `1`, but that result will applied on de `factorial(2)`, that are waiting at that moment for the result, and so on.

`After the return inside the if statement, the second return will continue to run?`

- Yes, the second if statement will continue to run, but it's like on other instance, that was waiting for the result.

`And if it return 1, the second return continue to run and it will do 5 * 1 forever (let's say n reaches 5)???`

- No. The `n` will be multiplied with the result of next call (the outer call waits for the inner call):

  ```
  5 * factorial(4)
      4 * factorial(3)
          3 * factorial(2)
              2 * factorial(1)
                  1
              2 * 1 = 2
          3 * 2 = 6
      4 * 6 = 24
  5 * 24 = 120
  ```

```js
function factorial(n, indent) {
    if (!indent) indent = '';
    console.log(indent+'BEGIN: factorial('+n+')');
    if (n === 1) {
        console.log(indent+'END: factorial('+n+'): 1');
        return 1;
    }
    let factorialNMinus1 = factorial(n - 1, indent + '    ');
    let result = n * factorialNMinus1 ;
    console.log(indent+'END: factorial('+n+'): ' + n + ' * ' + factorialNMinus1 + ' = ' + result);
    return result;  
}

console.log('result = ' + factorial(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way of analyzing recursion is by using a simple situation, and think how the recursion will unfold.

Lets say n = 3.

```js
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);  
}

console.log(factorial(3));
```

So, the following iterations will happen:

```
fac(3)   == 3 * fac(3-1)
fac(3-1) == 3-1 * fac(2-1)
fac(2-1) == 2-1 * 1
```

The condition that makes the recursion unfold and start returning is `n == 1`, so when that happens, the last function call will return 1 instead of calling itself again.

But the actual result will be the sum of all returned operations: (3 * ((3-1) * ((2-1) * 1)))

So, factorial(5) returns 120 because: (5 * ((5-1) * ((4-1) * ((3-1) * ((2-1) * 1))))) == 120.